# Problems with CORS Response to preflight in dotnet core 3.1

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am facing this issue:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/api/surpactemp/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

On backend side I tried this way and didn't worked:

```
.AllowAnyOrigin()
.AllowAnyHeader()
.AllowAnyMethod()
```

I've been trying several ways to solve using Microsoft reference (below), but, no success so far.
Also, I already tried not pass the headers object on Angular, then, I receive the error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested

**Environment**:

- Dotnet Core 3.1
- Angular 8

**Backend**: Startup.cs

```
//ConfigureServices
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "CorsPolicy",
        builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                          .WithHeaders(HeaderNames.ContentType, "application/json")
                          .WithMethods("PUT", "DELETE", "GET", "OPTIONS", "POST")        
        );
});

//Configure
 app.UseHttpsRedirection();

 app.UseRouting();

 app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

 app.UseAuthorization();

 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
 {
     endpoints.MapControllers();
 });
```

**Frontend**: form-service.ts

```
httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      // 'withCredentials': 'false',
      // 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
};

return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:5000/api/surpactemp/', JSON.stringify(data.path), this.httpOptions);
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#preflight-requests

Comment: Where's your call to `UseCors`? It's position within the middleware pipeline setup is important.

Comment: @KirkLarkin On Backend section, app.UseCors("CorsPolicy")

Comment: Yeah, I know. I mean where is it within `Startup.Configure`? Which other calls is it between? Middleware order is important, so it's _possible_ you've got the order wrong.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I discovered the issue, the `app.UseHttpsRedirection()` method requires `https` clients.

On `Startup.cs` at `Configure` method:

```
//app.UseHttpsRedirection(); <-- Commented this line

app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors();

app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: Thanks, saved me some time, I was also querying an http endpoint

Comment: Thanks. Helped me too.

Answer (score 2):

This solution solved my case:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddCors();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors(
                options => options.SetIsOriginAllowed(x => _ = true).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials()
            );

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

from https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/16672

Answer (score 0):

```
services.AddCors(); // Make sure you call this previous to AddMvc
services.AddMvc();       

 app.UseCors(
     options => options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200","https://localhost:4200")
                .AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials()
             );
```

Edited:

```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseCors(
         options => options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "https://localhost:4200").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials());




            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();


            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

        }
```

Comment: Same, didn't work... Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/api/surpactemp/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's this that is the problem (went away as soon as I realized the redirection is being done in my service with  `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` and the javascript calls were to the "http", instead of "https".  I wish the error was more specific, but this fixed it!

Answer (score -2):

You can use proxy configuration.

look this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D9oFe6rHjpY

Comment: Hi, I already tried by this way using proxy on Angular, and didn't worked as well...