# CORS Issue with Dotnet 5 Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, cors, .net-5

I have a dotnet 5 web API with an Angular2+ front end, which I'm building from a previous 3.1 MVC version of the app. I'm having an issue with CORS while looking to authenticate with Yahoo that I did not have with the MVC version. The error I am getting is:

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.login.yahoo.com...' (redirected from 'https://localhost:5003/api/draft/yahooauth/') from origin 'https://localhost:5003' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

My API Controller:

```
        [EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
        [HttpPost("yahooauth")]
        public void YahooAuth()
        {
            string leftUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}", HttpContext.Request.Scheme, HttpContext.Request.Host);

            string returnUrl = $"{leftUrl}/api/draft/yahooexchange";

            string id = configuration["YahooClientId"];
            string secret = configuration["YahooClientSecret"];

            string url = $"https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth?client_id={id}&redirect_uri={returnUrl}&response_type=code&language=en-us";

            Response.Redirect(url);            
        }

        [HttpGet("yahooexchange/{code}")]
        public IActionResult yahooexchange(string code)
        {
            // Code that is supposed to be triggered with returnUrl from Yahoo
        }
```

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
    {

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) => Configuration = configuration;

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential 
                // cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                // requires using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<IdentityDbCxt>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityDb")));
            services.AddDbContext<DraftContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("FSDraftDb")));

            services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(opts =>
            {
                opts.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityDbCxt>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
            services.AddTransient<IAPICall, APICall>();

            services.AddTransient<IDraftService, DraftService>();

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.WithOrigins("*")
                                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                                            .AllowAnyMethod();
                    });
            });


            services.AddMvc()
                .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
            services.AddMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession();
            services.AddSingleton<IHtmlSanitizer, HtmlSanitizer>();
            services.AddControllersWithViews(/*options =>
                options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute())*/);
            

            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
            {
                options.SwaggerDoc("v1",
                    new OpenApiInfo { Title = "API", Version = "v1" });
            });

            services
                .AddControllers()
                .AddNewtonsoftJson();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider services)
        {
            //app.UseMiddleware<GCMiddleware>();
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            }


            app.UseStatusCodePages();
            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "angular_fallback",
                    pattern: "{target:regex(draft|data|keeper|adminapi|admin`):nonfile}/{*catchall}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });

            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
            {
                options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                string strategy = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DevTools:ConnectionStrategy");

                if (strategy == "proxy")
                {
                    spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://127.0.0.1:4200");
                }
                else if (strategy == "managed")
                {
                    spa.Options.SourcePath = "../ClientApp";
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer("start");
                }
            });



        }
    }
```

I've looked at a few sources, including one quite hopeful post here, but this did not solve my problem: [Problems with CORS Response to preflight in dotnet core 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61279426/problems-with-cors-response-to-preflight-in-dotnet-core-3-1)

In case it's helpful, I'm looking to do step 2: https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/flows_authcode/

Edit: This is the documentation I used regarding CORS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0#attr

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I ended up figuring out a workaround and just created a new MVC controller, as my previous MVC app worked fine.

In addition, I realized that I had not updated my Yahoo Developer App for the new return URI. This did not fix my CORS problem, but it was preventing this from properly working.

Code from Angular to go to the new controller.

```
window.location.href = "https://localhost:5003/yahoo/index";
```

My MVC Controller:

```
public class YahooController : Controller
    {
        private IAPICall apiCall;

        public YahooController(IAPICall aCall)
        {
            apiCall = aCall;
        }

        // getting session data on player values
        private DraftService GetDS()
        {
            DraftService draftService = HttpContext.Session.GetJson<DraftService>("DraftService") ?? new DraftService();
            return draftService;
        }

        // saving session data on player values
        private void SaveDS(DraftService ds)
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetJson("DraftService", ds);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public void Index()
        {
            string returnUrl = Url.Action("yahooexchange",
                  "yahoo", new
                  {

                  },
                   protocol: HttpContext.Request.Scheme);
            
            string url = apiCall.YahooAuthUrl(returnUrl);

            Response.Redirect(url);
        }

        public void yahooexchange(string code)
        {
            string content = apiCall.YahooGetToken(code);

            var jContent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(content);


            string accessToken = jContent.GetValue("access_token").ToString();
            string refreshToken = jContent.GetValue("refresh_token").ToString();

            string leftUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}", HttpContext.Request.Scheme, HttpContext.Request.Host);

            DraftService ds = GetDS();


            ds.YahooAccessToken = accessToken;
            ds.YahooRefreshToken = refreshToken;

            SaveDS(ds);

            string url = leftUrl + "/draft/" + ds.DraftId;

            Response.Redirect(url);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this syntax and move AddCors to the top of ConfigureServices. Assign name to UseRouting.

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));

.......
            ....
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
             app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
             .....
```

Comment: I'm getting an error, saying: "No overload for method 'UseRouting' takes 1 arguments". I believe this is due to using app.AddEndpoints.

Comment: @tp803 I am sorry , It was a typo.  I fixed it to app.UseCors("MyPolicy"); Try it again.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Unfortunately, that does not solve the issue. I'm wondering if there is another service that I'm using that is causing this?

Comment: @tp803 Try to remove   [EnableCors("MyPolicy")] from the controller

Comment: I tried that too, and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: It seems to me that  the API Cors is ok ,  you have problem with https://api.login.yahoo.com Cors. Discuss with the site admin

Comment: While there was something wrong with my Yahoo setup - I hadn't registered the new URL as a valid return URI - this did not solve my problem. I ended up just doing a workaround and used an MVC controller to do this. Thanks for the help though!